# Which version of php is PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19

Tags: php

Is it PHP version 5.3.2 or PHP version 5.3.2.1 or some other version and only the first 3 digits are shown? Where can I find this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upstream version is PHP 5.3.2. `1ubuntu4.19` is the Ubuntu revision of the package. Check

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/deb-version.5.html

for more information.

Comment: So, is it 5.3.2? Is `PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19` not the 5.3.25 version ?

Comment: It's 5.3.2, otherwise it would be called `PHP/5.3.25-something`.